# "Es wäre einer Überlegung wert" oder "Es wäre eine Überlegung wert"

Tags: grammatical-case

Wie ist es richtig:

1. Es wäre eine Überlegung wert
2. Es wäre einer Überlegung wert

Ich sehe "sein + wert" sehr oft mit Genitiv:

- Es ist nicht der Mühe wert.
- Es ist nicht der Rede wert.
- Nicht der Rede wert!

Aber mir scheint mit "Uberlegung" Akkusativ richtig zu sein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Üblicher und etwas geschliffener im Ausdruck ist wohl

> Es wäre einer Überlegung wert.

mit Genitiv. Auch die Wendungen

> Es ist nicht der Rede wert.
>
> Es ist nicht der Mühe wert.

klingen stilistisch sauberer mit Genitiv.

Die zugrundeliegende Wendung ist "einer Sache wert sein". Diese wird üblicherweise mit Genitiv gebildet. Frag' nicht warum. So hat es sich im Laufe von hunderten von Jahren der Sprachverwendung halt etabliert. (Oder lies unten die Antwort von Tofro mit der Unterscheidung von "würdig" und "wert".)

Der Duden (Universalwörterbuch, 2. Auflage, 1998) verzeichnet (und erlaubt) jedoch beide Varianten: "Einer Sache wert sein" (Genitiv) wird als Hauptvariante geführt, "eine Sache wert sein" (Akkusativ) als seltenere Form.

Es gilt bei Sprachen ja immer: Richtig ist, was sich durchsetzt. Wenn immer mehr Leute statt "einer Sache wert sein" (Genitiv) "eine Sache wert sein" (Akkusativ) sagen, dann wird es irgendwann die Norm. - Das geht sogar dem individuellen Hirn so: Auch wert-sein-Sätze, die typischerweise mit Genitiv gebildet werden, fangen an, normal zu klingen, wenn man sie 50 mal wiederholt.

Allerdings liegt die Tücke im Detail bzw. in der Einzelwendung:

Eine Phrase wie

> Athen ist eine Reise wert.

wird eigentlich immer mit Akkusativ gebildet. Man würde kaum sagen "Athen ist einer Reise wert" (Genitiv), auch wenn es grammatisch-technisch möglich sein sollte. Auch würde man wohl eher sagen

> Das ist einen Versuch wert.

(Akkusativ) und nicht etwa "Das ist eines Versuchs wert" (Genitiv), obwohl es grammatisch wohl nicht falsch wäre. Mit Genitiv klänge es aber überkandidelt.

> Dieser Aufsatz ist der Veröffentlichung wert.

schreit jedoch wieder nach dem Genitiv, denn "Dieser Aufsatz ist die Veröffentlichung wert" klingt komisch oder trägt sogar eine etwas andere Bedeutung mit sich.

<sub>(Etwa: Da wurde ein Sammelband mit Aufsätzen publiziert, die alle eigentlich Schrott sind. Ein einziger Aufsatz ist jedoch wirklich extrem gut, so dass man finden kann: "Alleine wegen dieses Aufsatzes war es gut, dass das Buch gedruckt wurde." Dann kann man sagen: "Dieser Aufsatz ist die Veröffentlichung wert." Das ist aber eine andere Bedeutung von 'Veröffentlichung'.)</sub>

Dagegen möchte

> Dieser Aufsatz ist das Papier nicht wert

lieber den Akkusativ. "Dieser Aufsatz ist des Papiers nicht wert" (Genitiv) habe ich in der Praxis noch nie gehört (auch wenn es, wie gesagt, grammatisch zulässig sein sollte).

Fazit: Je nach Wendung ist mal die Genitiv-Form, mal die Akkusativ-Form üblich(er) und vorzuziehen. Man kann jedoch meistens beide Kasus verwenden, ohne sich eines echten Grammatikfehlers (Genitiv!) schuldig zu machen.

Ein Dativ übrigens ist hier weit und breit nicht zu sehen. Vermutlich verwechselst du die Fälle, weil die Formen oft identisch sind (wem - der Mühe, wessen - der Mühe).

Comment: Anstatt nur belesen zu sein könntest du ja mal lesen, was andere dazu schreiben, das könnte deine Gedanken entwirren. http://canoo.net/blog/2008/03/26/ist-die-sache-die-oder-der-muhe-wert/

Answer (score 6):

Beides ist im Prinzip richtig, hat aber leicht unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wert) besitzt das Adjektiv *wert* eine veraltende Nebenbedeutung im Sinne von "würdig", die mit dem Genitiv steht und z.B. in stehenden Wendungen wie "nicht der Rede wert" oder "aller Ehren wert" noch lebendig ist:

> Das wäre einer Überlegung wert

bedeutet "Das ist einer Überlegung *würdig*" - Die "Qualität" von "das" im Sinne von "würdig sein" steht im Vordergrund. Diese Verwendung ist wie gesagt, allerdings schon fast verschwunden.

Dann gibt es noch die heute üblichere Bedeutung "etwas wert sein" (im Sinne von "das ist 5€ wert"), hier geht es mehr um den materiellen Wert der "Investition".

> Das wäre eine Überlegung wert

Sagt aus, dass es sich eventuell lohnen könnte, eine Überlegung zu investieren. Es geht also mehr um das Ergebnis bzw. das "Kosten/Nutzen-Verhältnis".

Und es gibt auch die Verwendung mit dem Dativ:

> Das ist **mir** eine Überlegung wert.

Was bedeutet, dass **ich** bereit bin, die Überlegung zu investieren.

Comment: Das ist eine erhellende Notiz. Sie erklärt auch die meisten Fälle aus meiner kleinen Sammlung unten (andere Antwort). Allerdings müsste es dann eigentlich "Athen ist einer Reise wert" (Genitiv, würdig) heißen, nicht etwa "Athen ist eine Reise wert" (Akkusativ, Tauschwert). Dito für "Das ist einen Versuch wert" - Hier scheint deine - an sich luzide - sprachhistorische Erklärung ihre Kraft zu verlieren... oder?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann warum? Du kannst sowohl sagen "Athen ist des Aufwands, dahin zu reisen, würdig" alls auch "Athen [zu besuchen] ist die Investition, 1000€ für den Flug dahin auszugeben wert". Es hat sich eben Letzteres eingebürgert. Es gibt viele Fälle, wo die Bedeutung zwischen "würdig" und "Einsatz wert" verschwimmt. Um zu erklären, worin die beiden Bedeutungen bestehen, muß man sie eben auseinanderziehen. Ich empfehle, den Eintrag zu "wert" im Grimmschen Wörterbuch zu lesen, der ist trotz seines Alters sehr erhellend.

Comment: Mein Problem mit "Athen ist eine Reise wert" kommt daher, dass die Reise ja nicht das Tauschobjekt ist, für das ich Athen bekomme (wie etwa der Euro das Tauschobjekt wäre, für das ich ein Bier bekomme); insofern funktioniert für mich die Wert-Logik (im Gegensatz zur würdig-Logik) hier nicht. Außer ich böge die Dinge so zurecht, dass "Reise" hier metonymisch für "den Preis der Reise" steht, nicht die Reise an sich. Jedoch ist eben "Athen ist eine Reise wert" doch viel leichter erklärt über die würdig-Logik, und dies dann ohne jegliche Bemühung einer Metonymie.

Comment: Der wichtigste Teil dieser Antwort sind die zwei Wörtlein «veraltende Nebenbedeutung».

Answer (score -1):

> Es wäre eine Überlegung wert.

oder

> Einer Überlegung wert sein.

Die Satzstellung macht es aus.

Bei deinem Beispiel ist `Es wäre eine Überlegung wert.` richtig.